# How to show the outdated comments, without having to click each outdated comment?

Tags: github

On GitHub, after opening the link of a pull request, the review comments on commits older than the current commit are hided, because they are outdated. I have to click "Show Outdated" for each such comments to see them. Is there a simpler way to show the outdated comments, without having to click each outdated comment? Thanks.

Comment: Here is a youtube video "how to unfold all collapsed comments on github": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C9-mnjE-N-g

Answer (score 1):

One alternative approach would be to use the GitHub API.
Specifically, [List comments on a pull request](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/comments/#list-comments-on-a-pull-request) (which list *all* comments, even outdated ones)

For instance, consider the script [`rwilcox/view_all_comments_for_pr.sh`](https://gist.github.com/rwilcox/6064298)

The main part of that script includes:

```
curl --user "$GITHUB_USERNAME:$GITHUB_PASSWORD" \
   --request GET \
   https://api.github.com/repos/$ORGANIZATION/$REPO/pulls/$PULL_NUMBER/comments | \
$JGREP -s "body diff_hunk user.login _links.html.href path original_position position" | \
perl -i -p -e 's/\\n/\n/g' | fold -w 80 -s
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the shell script call some methods in the GitHub API? Are GitHub API methods provided in some programming language other than bash, so how can the shell script invoke the methods in GitHub API?

Comment: @Tim `https://api.github.com/repos/$ORGANIZATION/$REPO/pulls/$PULL_NUMBER/comments` is the GitHub API method. That web API can be wrapped in multiple languages: https://developer.github.com/libraries/. So you don't have to do just curl in a bash, but you can script or program it.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean a HTTP request for `https://api.github.com/repos/$ORGANIZATION/$REPO/pulls/$PULL‌​_NUMBER/comments` will call a GitHub API method to run on the web server, and the output of the API method will be returned in the HTTP response to the HTTP request?

Comment: @Tim yes, that is what is explained in https://developer.github.com/v3/, and https://developer.github.com/guides/getting-started/ or https://gist.github.com/caspyin/2288960